# Add quadratic regression line to existing ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, non-linear-regression

I have fit a linear model and a polynomial model onto to same dataframe and would like to plot both lines on the same scattergraph.

I have the following code to show my linear model's line, how do i add the polynomial model (pm1) to this?

I am looking for an output similar to the image below.
[image]

I'm open to abandoning the ggplot if needed

```
ggplot(A1, aes(x = PopMns, y = Freq)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
  geom_line()
```

This is the dataframe i am working with. I am trying plot the lines of both a linear and non linear model to a scattergraph based off of this.

```
year Freq PopTotal   PopMns
1 1970  611  3700437 3700.437
2 1971  436  3775760 3775.760
3 1972  515  3851651 3851.651
4 1973  436  3927781 3927.781
5 1974  531  4003794 4003.794
6 1975  685  4079480 4079.480
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
#Code
ggplot(A1, aes(x = PopMns, y = Freq)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red",se=F) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "blue",formula = y~poly(x,2),se=F) +
  geom_line()
```

This results in the following
[image]

Is there a way to have the scatter points instead of the black line?

**Update:** Try this, using your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(A1, aes(x = PopMns, y = Freq)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red",se=F) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "blue",se=F,formula = y~poly(x,2))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. That does work, however it removes the indiviudal data points and creates a joined up line. I will try and put the result in the main question

Comment: @SlowBear Please also add a sample of your data to fully help you! Thanks, you can use `dput(yourdata)` and paste the output in your question by editing it!

Comment: @SlowBear Please could you elaborate what you expect, I am not clear what is your issue now. I have added an update please check!

Comment: @Duck...apologies I will try to better explain.
I have data which shows number of incidents (Y) plotted against world population (X). I have fitted both a linear and non-linear model based of this data and I would like to show both lines on the same scatter graph. 
Essentially I want to illustrate that the second (non linear) model shows a better fit.
Does that help?

Comment: @SlowBear The plot you added, is showing what you want, what else do you expect in the plot?

Comment: I have just added a image to the question which hopefully explains. I'd like something similar to the scattergraph in the image, but obviously with a linear and non-linear line as opposed to two linear lines

Comment: @SlowBear Just a second, I believe I know what you need!

Comment: @SlowBear I have added an update using your new data, please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: That gives almost the exact same output as the previous code unfortunately. By that I mean it has the black, joined up line as opposed to the scatter of data points. The red and blue lines for each model are working though which is good.

Although I've just realised because there is only one data point for each year I will never have a "scatter"will I. With that being said I think your solution is the answer I need. Thanks and apologies for the back and forth...I've been looking at the screen for too long

Comment: @SlowBear Remove any geom_line in your code, that will leave only the points.